# Constraints not working across multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I am attempting to get my constraints set correctly, and I thought I had them right, but when viewing the app on the iPad its screwing things up.

I have several screen shots of the ipad layouts and the list of constraints, if anyone can help me determine what to try next I'm all ears.

Interestingly enough, the app works fine on all iphone apps and it works fine on the ipad pro 12" screen.

On the first two images you can see how its still shifting everything despite having a pin to the top plus 20 pixels... unless I'm not understanding that aspect.

[image: iPad Air 2]

[image: ipad Pro 9.7]

[image: iPad Pro 12.9]

[image: Constraints]

Comment: Change deployment info and chose the target as universal

Comment: This is strictly for an iPhone but according to Apple it must allow for all devices...but that aside, even changing the app to universal it still does the same thing.

Comment: If you are developing only iPhone app then no need to satisfy iPad constraints

Comment: Well according to Apple I do.  They won't approve an app that does not display at its target size on an ipad.  Apple response as follows: "In order to bring your app into compliance with the 2.4.1 guideline, please revise your app to ensure it runs and displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad. Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use your app on iPad.

Best Regards,
App Store Review"

Comment: It seems you have chosen device target as iPhone, please make sure it is Universal in Target-> DeploymentInfo -> Devices to Universal

Comment: Ok, let me explain this again, YES I DID - but it does not matter its doing the same thing regardless of deployment.  Furthermore, its an iPhone only app but Apple requires it work on the ipad as well.  See comment above.

Comment: Did you use "Vary for Traits" for any of your constraints?

Comment: @Beth.larson1977 - you understood correctly from the beginning... do **NOT** set your target for Universal.

Comment: No I did not use Vary for Traits, I'll go look at what that does and try it Don.  Is there a way to modify the existing constraint to add that?

Comment: @Beth.larson1977 - I'd suggest taking a step back for a minute... Your 12.9 iPad image doesn't even look correct, as it has a "white bar" across the top that is not apparent in your storyboard image. Your ViewController is pretty simple - only a few elements... so try creating a new VC and add things in one at a time. Start with the image view - get it to size and position itself correctly, and then start adding the rest. (and with this layout, you *shouldn't* need Vary for Traits).

Comment: By the way... what is the Content Mode set to for your Image View? Is it `Scale To Fill`?

Comment: Don, content mode is currently Aspect Fill

Comment: @Beth.larson1977 - ah, I'm betting that's part of the problem. First, change your image view to `Clip To Bounds` (checkbox under Attributes Inspector). You *might* be happy with the result. If not, change it to `Scale To Fill`, then to `Aspect Fit` and then back to `Aspect Fill`. Notice the differences. You might need to edit your image aspect ratio, or use the Background Color of the image view to "pad out" the image so you like the result.

Comment: my bet is this not in Universal mode. If so, you would never see 2x or 1x button

Comment: That got me close Don, close enough for me :) Thanks for the help!  I don't see where i can mark your answer as a solution.